# Telegram Bot InlineKeyboardButton Full Text

Tags: bots, telegram-bot, chatbot, python-telegram-bot

I am using `InlineKeyboardButton` to create buttons in telegram bot, like the following.

```
keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
             InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2. Long text here. Long text here. Long text here.", callback_data='2'), 
             InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')]]

reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

In this example, Button 2 text will be truncated to something like "Option 2. Long text here...". I wonder if it's possible to show full text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On desktops hovering a cursor over such button will display it's full text in tooltip, on mobile pressing and holding such button *should* do the same.

You could also reply to the user on this specific callback data with **answerCallbackQuery** method with `text` set to your full text (maximum of 200 characters allowed though) and `show_alert` to `true`, that will display a popup message to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the message's length above the buttons as long as the text that you would like to use in the button 2.

It stretches the button's length.